# SQL : Get a Date Closest to the Specific Date from a Column Of Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Two Columns "Need by date" and "Exp Date" as follows :

```
Need By Date |   Exp Date      | final Exp Date
2018-02-06      2016-07-31         2019-01-01
2018-02-06      2017-04-01         2019-01-01
2018-02-06      2019-01-01         2019-01-01
2018-02-06      2019-06-01         2019-01-01
2018-02-06      2019-09-01         2019-01-01
```

I need get a column "Final Exp Date" i.e. the date closest after the "Need by date" !! How can go about this problem.

In this example "Final Exp Date" column is what i am expecting to see .Which in this case "Need by date" is " 2018-02-06" the date greater than and closest to "2018-02-06" is "2019-01-01"

Comment: "I need get a column "Final Exp Date" i.e. the date closet after the "Need by date"" what do you mean by that ?

Comment: Means "Final Exp Date" column is what i am expecting to see .Which in this case "Need by date" is " 2018-02-06"  the date greater than and closest to 2018-02-06 is   2019-01-01 .

Comment: How do you define the "most closest date" as 2019-01-01 ? You expect "the next year's first day"  ?

Comment: so you have no id's in the table? just these 2 columns?

Comment: @YasinBilir : No Just any date that is after "Need by Date" it can even be "2018-03-06" !!

Comment: @vkp : i do have other columns since there were too many columns i just got these two in here to make it more presentable and understandable .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any further date after Needbydate, try this;

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,ROUND(((1000 - 3 -1) * RAND() + 1), 0),@Needbydate)

It will add some days to your needbydate date randomly.

If you want to get the first day of the next year, try this;

SELECT DATEADD(year,+1,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,@Needbydate),0))

Comment: Its not just any date , The date has to be in "Exp Date" column . If in my "Exp date" there was date "2018-03-06" i should see this date in "Final Exp date"      #referring to the comment

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys if i was not clear on what i was asking . 
I figured out the answer

```
(select top 1 ExpDate from OBTN where ExpDate > Need by date order by s100.ExpDate)
```

Thank you for your time